# Can't install php-xml for symfony

Tags: php, symfony, centos, centos6

I'm trying to install symfony on centos6 
I installed php, but when i start the built-in server this error appeared

```
[RuntimeException]          
Extension DOM is required.
```

I tried `yum install php-xml`

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.i686
```

I'm using 32 bits centos6 and 5.6.32 php version.

I tried to update my yum command with the last epel release and typed this command :

```
yum -y install php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd 
php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath php56u-soap
```

after downloading the packages he can't proceed to install them.
any idea of how can I install dom extension of php 5.6.* into centos6 i386?

Answer (score 0):

It seems php 5.3 is installed on your server.
Try to remove php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.i686 ?

```
yum remove php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.i686
```

Then, try to run your command :

```
yum -y install php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd 
php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath php56u-soap
```